# Can't get IIS to listen on virtual host

Tags: iis

This should be very simple, but I'm having some serious issues with something else that might be related in this ticket:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311346/cant-listen-on-anything-but-localhost-asp-net-mvc-framework-iis-express/63332481#63332481

This issue might provide some insight into the other issue.  I have about 5 tickets with Microsoft and one of the Gurus there suggested I try Local IIS.

So I installed IIS.  I have a No Managed Code server running on localhost just fine.  I can pull up the iisstart.htm page. If I change the binding to eadev, it stops working.

hosts file
`127.0.0.1       eadev`

```
jbaro@ezio MINGW64 ~
$ ping eadev

Pinging eadev [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

jbaro@ezio MINGW64 ~
$ curl eadev
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to eadev port 80: Connection refused
```

Switch binding to eadev

```
jbaro@ezio MINGW64 ~
$ curl localhost
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   696  100   696    0     0   113k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  113k<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
...
```

Switch binding back to eadev

```
jbaro@ezio MINGW64 ~
$ curl localhost
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   315  100   315    0     0  78750      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 78750<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

If I had to guess: It doesn't like that eadev isn't being resolved by the DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the --resolve switch with cURL which will tell cURL to resolve eadev to 127.0.0.1, see below:

```
curl --resolve 'eadev:80:127.0.0.1' http://eadev/
```

Comment: Connection refused.  It's also not working in the browser.

Comment: My answer is based on the fact that cURL is running on the same machine as the web server. If you are using cURL on a machine other than the IIS server, you need to set eadev in the hosts file on that machine executing cURL to point to the IP address of the server running IIS and ensure the relevant ports are open in the firewall then run the command above (substituting 127.0.0.1 for the correct IP), as 127.0.0.1 is a loopback address.

Comment: I just tried from another computer to confirm, same issue.